# Can private sub pass newly created variable to main()?

Tags: string, vb.net, module, parameter-passing, program-entry-point

Can private sub program being in the same module as main after receiving value from main, creates new variable and pass it back to main?

This is what I am trying to do, but I am having some difficulties. 
For example, in testSUB below I altered the string. Can I pass extraSTRING and newSTRING back to main? Any examples would be helpful.

```
Module module1
    Sub main()
        Dim l As String
        Dim I As Long = 1
        Dim A As String
        testsub(l, A, I)
    End Sub

    Private Sub testSub(l As String, A As String, I As Long)
        Dim extraSTRING As String = "extraTEXT"
        Dim newSTRING As String = l & extraSTRING
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're after in this example. However you could turn testSub into a function and return something that way. Or you could use [ByRef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx) for the parameters passed.

Comment: @Jinx88909 : It seems to me that is what he wants. You should write an answer with those two options.

Comment: @VisualVincent posted as answer. On my mobile so hopefully I've not made any mistakes. Not as easy :)

Comment: When a sub routine accepts parameters, it can do so in 1 of 2 ways - Byref or byval. Byval is the default and means that the value you passed is will be replicated in memory. Byref means that you want to pass a memory address or Pointer. When the subroutine acts on a reference value then the modifications to that value are inherently noticed by the caller. @Jinx88909 has answered your question.

Alternatively you could simply write a function instead of a sub.
A Private declaration means that it's only available inside that module.

Comment: @Jinx88909 : Heh, I write almost all my answers from my phone. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the information. It's really informative and helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return a value you could turn your `Sub` into a `Function`:

```
Private Function testFunction (ByVal arg1 As String) As String

    Return arg1 & " and some more text"

End Function
```

To call the above `Function` and assign the value returned use this code:

```
Dim a As String = testFunction("some text")

'Output:
'a = "some text and some more text"
```

Below is a screenshot of the code with the output:

[image]

Alternatively you can use [ByRef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c84t73c2.aspx):

> Specifies that an argument is passed in such a way that the called procedure can change the value of a variable underlying the argument in the calling code.

`ByRef` differs slightly from [ByVal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2b185t2.aspx):

> Specifies that an argument is passed in such a way that the called procedure or property cannot change the value of a variable underlying the argument in the calling code.

Below is some sample code showing you the differences in action:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a As Integer = 0
        Dim b As Integer = 0
        Dim c As Integer = 0

        testSub(a, b, c)

        'Output:
        'a = 0
        'b = 0
        'c = 3

    End Sub

    Private Sub testSub(arg1 As Integer, ByVal arg2 As Integer, ByRef arg3 As Integer)
        arg1 = 1
        arg2 = 2
        arg3 = 3
    End Sub

End Module
```

By not specifying a `modifier` in `VB.NET` (as shown with `arg1` above) the compiler by default will use `ByVal`.

> It would be good to note here that although `VB.NET` uses `ByVal` by default if not specified, `VBA` does not and instead by default uses `ByRef`. Beware of this should you ever port code from one to the other.

Below is a screenshot of the code with the output:

[image]

Using your code as an example:

```
Sub main()
    Dim l As String
    Dim A As String
    Dim I As Long = 1
    testSub(l, A, I)
End Sub
```

To pass the variables `l`, `A` and `I` and have their value changed you would change your method to use the modifier `ByRef`.

```
Private Sub testSub(ByRef l As String, ByRef A As String, ByRef I As Long)
    l = "TEXT"
    A = "extra" & l
    I = 100
End Sub
```

Below is a screenshot of the code with the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the examples.

Comment: Thank you for the display. It makes it so clear and it does answered my question.